# Object of type 'Response' has no len() in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

ive combined two models. one model's field is annotated to another model's so they can merge. However, when I try to return the data, I get `TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()`. I've followed several examples on stackoverflow and it doesnt seem to be working.

Here's what I have:

```
class ExploreAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        merged_queryset = Place.get_queryset(self.request.user)
        usr_pks = [u.pk for u in merged_queryset]
        queryset = Place.objects.filter(pk__in=usr_pks)

        serialUser = UserSerializer( User.objects.annotate(time=Extract('date_joined','epoch')), many=True).data[:]
        serialPlace = PlacesSerializer(queryset, many=True).data[:]

        chained_list = sorted(serialPlace +serialUser, key=lambda x: x.get('time'))

        return Response(chained_list)
```

I dont understand why it returns no `len()` when it returns items if i print out the `chained_list`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're returning a Response from `get_queryset`. But that method is supposed to return a queryset, as the name implies.

Comment: what do you mean? it's not returning the `query_set` shown here but from the model.

Comment: You are not supposed to return an instance of Response from that method. You are supposed to return a queryset.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielRoseman What response should we return if the queryset is not found?